# Open photos library or camera from WKWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, camera, wkwebview, photo

I have an app that contains the `WKWebView` and within the webview we have the functionality to attach image from photos library. This thing works fine when the page is opened from Safari or Chrome but in my app photos options does not open.

I have searched over several answers but they are telling to inject custom javascript to attach a listener. But nothing works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give permissions to the app manually in your code. So that your `WKWebView` can open the photo gallery.

Add the following two keys in your Info.plist file:

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Needs permission to select photos</string>
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Needs permission to take photos</string>
```

And add the following code to ask photos permissions before image attachment functionality is loaded in `WKWebView` (don't forget to `import Photos` framework):

```
    let status = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
    if status == .authorized {
        print("already authorized")
    } else {
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({(_ status: PHAuthorizationStatus) -> Void in
            switch status {
            case .authorized:
                print("Authorized")
            case .denied:
                print("Denied")
            case .notDetermined:
                print("Not determined")
            case .restricted:
                print("Restricted")
            @unknown default:
                print("Unknown")
            }
        })
    }
```